# Creating a table with a vertically separated header row and \hhline produces horizontal line distortion

Tags: tables, multicolumn, hhline, hline

I want to create a table which marks some cells either with `$\times$` or they simply stay empty.
I have two header rows of which I would like to separate the first header row visually. I use `\hhline{~======}` to get this visual separation. I resorted to using this additinoal package because I found, that a double `\hline` does not seem to work correctly with `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}`.

After finally having found a solution, I now get the problem, that the horizontal lines produced by `\hhline` are weirdly distorted:

[image]

Here's my minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
          & $T_1$    & $T_2$    & $T_3$    & $T_4$    & $T_5$    & $T_6$    \\ 
    \hhline{~ = = = = = =}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
          & $r_1$    & $r_2$    & $r_3$    & $r_4$    & $r_5$    & $r_6$    \\
    \hline
    $t_1$ &          & $\times$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          \\
    \hline
    $t_2$ & $\times$ &          & $\times$ &          &          &          \\
    \hline
    $t_3$ &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &          \\
    \hline
    $t_4$ & $\times$ &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
    \hline
    $t_5$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          &          & $\times$ \\
    \hline
    $t_6$ &          &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For me, it seems like an anti aliasing issue but I'm probably doing something wrong on my side. I would be glad if someone could point me to a fix or to an alternative solution that looks the same as it does now. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The rules here are built up by copies of smaller units.  This is probably about the best you can do with this type of syntax.  A different approach could be to use `tikz`, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204358/15925 for example.  The other extreme is to drop the vertical rules as suggested by the `bookmarks` package.

Comment: When I replace \hhline{~------} with ͵`\hhline{~ :=:=:=:=:=:=:}` and I measure the distance between the two horizontal lines at several points, I find exactly 2pt at each point. Maybe what you observe is just an optical effect? Or a problem with the pdf viewer? B.t.w., you should use \hhline  also for the following lines, to avoid holes in the outer vertical lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have a perfect output in all PDF viewers at all levels of zoom because the rules are drawn with the graphical layer PGF/Tikz (and not by concatenation of small characters).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}[corners]
    \Hline
          & $T_1$    & $T_2$    & $T_3$    & $T_4$    & $T_5$    & $T_6$    \\ 
    \Hline
    \Hline
          & $r_1$    & $r_2$    & $r_3$    & $r_4$    & $r_5$    & $r_6$    \\
    \Hline
    $t_1$ &          & $\times$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          \\
    \Hline
    $t_2$ & $\times$ &          & $\times$ &          &          &          \\
    \Hline
    $t_3$ &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &          \\
    \Hline
    $t_4$ & $\times$ &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
    \Hline
    $t_5$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          &          & $\times$ \\
    \Hline
    $t_6$ &          &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
    \Hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

As you can see, the vertical rules are not broken by the double horizontal rule (that's by design in `nicematrix`).

If you prefer to have the vertical rules borken (as with the standard behaviour of the tabulars in LaTeX), it's possible but a bit more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule}}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{lIcIcIcIcIcIcI}[corners]
    \Hline
          & $T_1$    & $T_2$    & $T_3$    & $T_4$    & $T_5$    & $T_6$    \\ 
    \Hline
    \Hline
          & $r_1$    & $r_2$    & $r_3$    & $r_4$    & $r_5$    & $r_6$    \\
    \Hline
    $t_1$ &          & $\times$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          \\
    \Hline
    $t_2$ & $\times$ &          & $\times$ &          &          &          \\
    \Hline
    $t_3$ &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &          \\
    \Hline
    $t_4$ & $\times$ &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
    \Hline
    $t_5$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          &          & $\times$ \\
    \Hline
    $t_6$ &          &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
    \Hline
  \CodeAfter \tikz \draw (3-|1) -- (last-|1) ;
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]