# Strange artifacts with \hhline

Tags: tables, line, bugs, hline, hhline

I'm trying to use `\hhline` to draw partial lines in my tables (for which I can't use `\cline` since my tables contain coloured cells and it is a well-known problem that this combination doesn't work). I'm noticing two kinds of artifacting, however (MWE below):

1. All `\hhline{=}`s aren't drawn as solid lines, but rather as dots and dashes, where vertical crossings have a longer darker dash. Although it is subtle, it is disturbing to the eye and appears at any zoom size in multiple different PDF viewers. It's not the case for a standard `\hline\hline` so it shouldn't be for `\hhline`.

[image]

2. When an `\hhline` is used *elsewhere* in a table, `\hline\hline` suddenly only breaks 3/4 of each vertical line that crosses it.

[image]

How do I get rid of these artifacts? (Before anyone suggests it: no, I'm not switching from `tabular` to `NiceMatrix`, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622092/203081).)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    A & B \\ \hhline{=:=}
    C & D
\end{tabular}
\hspace{2em}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    A & B \\ \hline\hline
    C & D
\end{tabular}
\hspace{2em}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    A & B \\ \hline\hline
    C & D \\ \hhline{~-}
    E & F 
\end{tabular}
\hspace{2em}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    A & B \\ \hline\hline
    C & D \\ \hline
    E & F 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe consider using `tabularray` instead to avoid such problems.

Comment: I know you state otherwise, but if this is what annoys you, you should *really* consider using the `nicematrix` package as it draws lines as one single stroke whereever this is possible.

Comment: @JasperHabicht The reason I don't want to switch over is because I am generating these tables automatically, and am letting LaTeX do the colouring with `\cellcolor` based on [this computation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642581/203081).

Comment: using xpdf I don't see the overprint as darker even at full zoom however it does overprint as a feature of standard array `|` add the `array` package.

Comment: `It's not the case for a standard \hline\hline so it shouldn't be for \hhline.`  er... that's like saying it's not the case that apples have orange skin so it shouldn't be the case for oranges.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does the orange purport to be different than an orange? Did you not write `\hhline{=...}` with the goal that it looked like `\hline\hline`?

Comment: yes but the whole point of hhline, unlike hline is that it is made up of multiple segments, so the fact that hline shows as a continuous line and hhline sometimes shows artifacts at the joins is hardly a surprise.  With the format version of tabular there is a negative space half the width of `|` so the segments will overlap, althoiugh as I say xpdf does not make that noticable as far as I can see the array package version of tabular does not have that negative space. I could not reproduce the vertical line overlapping into the double hline gap.